# Excel Formula Help - need to find duplicates between two sheets and then move info from a reference to a source

Tags: excel, formula, lookup, autofill

Search a range of cell values from one sheet (source) in another sheet (reference) and if found, return the value/s of data missing from the (source) that is already filled out in the (reference)

Comment: What have you tried and what is the exact problem you are facing. With the information given, there's not much anyone can say

Comment: I have tried vlookup, hlookup, xlookup, match, etc.  i keep getting spill error which shows me it is bringing back more than just the data value I am trying to get.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72306172/edit) to show us exactly what you have done. Some sample data and expected result would also be useful.